# how to passing arguments to an alias

Tags: bash, alias

i add an alias in .bashrc

alias sr='sudo /etc/rc.d/[parameter?] restart'

sr network ->  sudo /etc/rc.d/network restart

sr sshd    ->  sudo /etc/rc.d/sshd restart

could it be achieved, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a shell function instead. eg:

```
function sr () {
  sudo /etc/rc.d/"$1" restart
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned to use a function

```
function sr() { 
  sudo /etc/rc.d/"$@" restart 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function rather than an alias:

```
function sr() { sudo /etc/rc.d/$@ restart; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases in bash do not accept parameters.  However, you could define a function instead:

```
function sr() { sudo /etc/rc.d/$1 restart; }
```